# WPF Dynamic Ordering

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a Model with one of it property being **Order** with is a type of int. The model is put inside an **ObservableCollection** say for example **ModelList** is bound to a listbox.

Using this code

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{StaticResource ModelList}" x:Key="SortedItems">
  <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Order"/>
  </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Then this list is Bound to a listbox using

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedItems}}" />
```

Works Fines. But I want to change the order of the list by its Order property, that is when i change the Order via code I want the listbox to reflect the change.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resort a CollectionViewSource, you need to update the [SortDescriptions property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.sortdescriptions.aspx)

To access your CollectionViewSource from code, declare it in your viewmodel and bind to it (instead of declaring it in XAML). For items in the visual tree, you can use x:Name, though this does not seem to work from a Resources tag, at least via initial testing